# How can I add html into VBA?

Tags: regex, ms-access, vba

I'm trying to parse through some HTML code that I'd like to paste into my VBA function.  Essentially, i want to dim a string and then let the string = [INSERT HTML HERE].  Except if i tried to do that VBA would pick up on quotation marks and other symbols as VBA code and then give me a compile error of some sort.

I would parse the html first and either add quotation marks wherever i find a quotation mark or exit out all the symbols, but that would require pasting the html into a compiler that will have the same problem as before.  I really can't figure this out!

What can be done about this?  Is there a way for me to modify my regex pattern to automatically exit out the symbols?  I'm really at a loss.  I had one idea, but i can't figure out how to do this either.  If i could say string=[FILE CONTAINING HTML] then that would work as well.  any suggestions please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just open the HTML file and read it into a string variable. Here's an example.

http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?342619-Classic-VB-How-can-I-read-write-a-text-file

Comment: Hey that helped out a great deal, but I still have the same problem as before but this time when i'm trying to put regex code into vba. How do I get vba to just recognize what i'm typing as symbols and not as commands.

Comment: With reg
        .Pattern = "price"\>+([\d,.k]{1,})/"
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Global = False
        .Multiline = False
        Set colMatches = .Execute(str)
    End With                                                                                                                                               This will not compile with VBA.  I've tried escaping out of all the symbols with '\', but that doesent work either.

Comment: Edit your original question and post the code and the compile error.